# How deploy LinkChecker on a shared server

Tags: python, linkchecker

I have built a tool that does analysis and displays various client-specific data on her particular web site. I run LinkChecker locally on my windows machine from a command line.  It takes about an hour and produces a big XML output file. I ftp this file to the client's site, and it is traversed by an analysis tool I built. It works great, except that it is manual and not self contained. It need to run on the server under a cron job.

It is hosted at Pair on *nix in a shared environment (I don't know what variety, but I can find out), so I don't have a lot of privileges.

LinkChecker is written in python apparently. They have "instructions" for deploying on unix, but they cite the need for a C compiler (I don't think I have access), something called "pip", etc. I don't think I'll be allowed to install anything.

My question is- how can I get this installed in a shared environment? I can shell in, and I tried running "sudo pip install LinkChecker", but it said I was not in the list of "sudoers".

The "install.txt" file can be seen here:
https://github.com/wummel/linkchecker/blob/master/doc/install.txt

Comment: Have you contacted the sysadmin at Pair to ask whether it's possible to install the tool and run it as a cronjob? That'd be my first step (after checking any FAQ/docs about the server environment).

Comment: Fortunately, Pair is willing to install linkchecker for a small one time fee. I generally like to get my hands dirty with things like this, but in this case I don't want to risk breaking something on a production system, and don't have the time to experiment.
Thanks-